# Display slider on wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created another slider based on an example on a website:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGWPYp)

I would like to get exactly the same slider on my wordpress, buy when I past the code on my website I have the result of code snippet :( May you please take a look at this (if possible try it to check it). I tried for several days without success :(

Thanks

```css
$switch-speed: 1s;
$slider-number: 5;
$slider-width: 100% / $slider-number;

$image1: 'https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Salle-dattente.jpg';
$image2: 'https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Entrée.jpg';
$image3: 'https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Thérapie.jpg';
$image4: 'https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Cabinet.jpg';
$image5: 'https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Cure-type.jpg';

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1C2325;
  color: #eee;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

// basic styles
.s-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #efefe8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;

  > input {
    display: none;
  }

  .s-content {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% * $slider-number;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transition: transform $switch-speed;
  }

  .s-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: $slider-width;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .s-item-1 {background-image: url($image1);}
  .s-item-2 {background-image: url($image2);}
  .s-item-3 {background-image: url($image3);}
  .s-item-4 {background-image: url($image4);}
  .s-item-5 {background-image: url($image5);}
}

.s-type-1 {
  .s-control {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 18px;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;

    > label[class^="s-c-"] {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      background-color: #efefe8;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  .s-nav label {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;

    &::before,
    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 8px;
      height: 24px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    &::before {margin-bottom: -12px;}

    &.left {
      left: 20px;

      &::before {transform: rotate(45deg);}

      &::after {transform: rotate(-45deg);}
    }

    &.right {
      right: 20px;

      &::before {transform: rotate(-45deg);}

      &::after {transform: rotate(45deg);}
    }
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $slider-number {
    #s-#{$i}:checked {
      & ~ .s-content {transform: translateX(-$slider-width * ($i - 1));}

      & ~ .s-control .s-c-#{$i} {background-color: #333;}

      & ~ .s-nav .s-nav-#{$i} {display: block;}
    }
  }
}

.s-type-2 {
  .s-content {
    animation: slider-animation 50s ease-in-out infinite;

    &:hover {animation-play-state: paused;}
  }
}

@keyframes slider-animation {
  $i: 0;
  $j: 0;
  $times: ($slider-number - 1) * 2;
  @while $i < 100 {
    #{$i}%,
    #{$i + 7}% {
      @if $i < 50 {
        transform: translateX(-$slider-width * $j);
          } @else {
            transform: translateX(-$slider-width * ($times - $j));
              }
    }

    $i: $i + 100 / $times;
    $j: $j + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="outer-wrapper">
   <div class="s-wrap s-type-1" role="slider">
    <input type="radio" id="s-1" name="slider-control" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" id="s-2" name="slider-control">
    <input type="radio" id="s-3" name="slider-control">
    <input type="radio" id="s-4" name="slider-control">
    <input type="radio" id="s-5" name="slider-control">
    <ul class="s-content">
      <li class="s-item s-item-1"></li>
      <li class="s-item s-item-2"></li>
      <li class="s-item s-item-3"></li>
      <li class="s-item s-item-4"></li>
      <li class="s-item s-item-5"></li>
    </ul>
   <div class="s-nav">
      <label class="s-nav-1 right" for="s-2"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-2 left" for="s-1"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-2 right" for="s-3"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-3 left" for="s-2"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-3 right" for="s-4"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-4 left" for="s-3"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-4 right" for="s-5"></label>
      <label class="s-nav-5 left" for="s-4"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Did you convert the scss to css on wordpress?

Comment: Hi Vel, how can I do it?

Comment: updated as answer. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and also make sure you have "jquery" Js in you wordpress site, I have include jquery cdn into html code.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1C2325;
  color: #eee;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.s-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #efefe8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.s-wrap > input {
  display: none;
}
.s-wrap .s-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.s-wrap .s-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.s-wrap .s-item-1 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Salle-dattente.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-2 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Entrée.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-3 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Thérapie.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-4 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Cabinet.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-5 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Cure-type.jpg");
}

.s-type-1 .s-control {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.s-type-1 .s-control > label[class^="s-c-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #efefe8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label::before, .s-type-1 .s-nav label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label::before {
  margin-bottom: -12px;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.left {
  left: 20px;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.left::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.left::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.right {
  right: 20px;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.right::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.right::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.s-type-1 #s-1:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-1:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-1 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-1:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-1 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-2:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-2:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-2 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-2:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-2 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-3:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-40%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-3:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-3 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-3:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-3 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-4:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-60%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-4:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-4 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-4:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-4 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-5:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-80%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-5:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-5 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-5:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-5 {
  display: block;
}

.s-type-2 .s-content {
  animation: slider-animation 50s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.s-type-2 .s-content:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes slider-animation {
  0%,
    7% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  12.5%,
    19.5% {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
  25%,
    32% {
    transform: translateX(-40%);
  }
  37.5%,
    44.5% {
    transform: translateX(-60%);
  }
  50%,
    57% {
    transform: translateX(-80%);
  }
  62.5%,
    69.5% {
    transform: translateX(-60%);
  }
  75%,
    82% {
    transform: translateX(-40%);
  }
  87.5%,
    94.5% {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-wrapper">
      <div class="s-wrap s-type-1" role="slider">
       <input type="radio" id="s-1" name="slider-control" checked="checked">
       <input type="radio" id="s-2" name="slider-control">
       <input type="radio" id="s-3" name="slider-control">
       <input type="radio" id="s-4" name="slider-control">
       <input type="radio" id="s-5" name="slider-control">
       <ul class="s-content">
         <li class="s-item s-item-1"></li>
         <li class="s-item s-item-2"></li>
         <li class="s-item s-item-3"></li>
         <li class="s-item s-item-4"></li>
         <li class="s-item s-item-5"></li>
       </ul>
      <div class="s-nav">
         <label class="s-nav-1 right" for="s-2"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-2 left" for="s-1"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-2 right" for="s-3"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-3 left" for="s-2"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-3 right" for="s-4"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-4 left" for="s-3"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-4 right" for="s-5"></label>
         <label class="s-nav-5 left" for="s-4"></label>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, It works ! , you saved my life lol! Now I just have to resize the pictures for my wordpress theme. thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, one last thing. I think that the code is not responsive. I tried to edit a little bit the css code but all my pictures are not displayed entirely on the page. May you please take a look at my website: https://meshrepsy.fr/cabinet/

Comment: It was done. It works, the problem came from the border-box of my site.Thanks you for your precious help

Comment: I cannot get my slider responsive with the code. I tried to ass a css to get the images responsives but it did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

I have converted scss to css. Add this css in your active theme style.css

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1C2325;
  color: #eee;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.s-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #efefe8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.s-wrap > input {
  display: none;
}
.s-wrap .s-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.s-wrap .s-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.s-wrap .s-item-1 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Salle-dattente.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-2 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Entrée.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-3 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Thérapie.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-4 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Cabinet.jpg");
}
.s-wrap .s-item-5 {
  background-image: url("https://meshrepsy.fr/wp-content/uploads/Cure-type.jpg");
}

.s-type-1 .s-control {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.s-type-1 .s-control > label[class^="s-c-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #efefe8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label::before, .s-type-1 .s-nav label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label::before {
  margin-bottom: -12px;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.left {
  left: 20px;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.left::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.left::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.right {
  right: 20px;
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.right::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.s-type-1 .s-nav label.right::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.s-type-1 #s-1:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-1:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-1 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-1:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-1 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-2:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-2:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-2 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-2:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-2 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-3:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-40%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-3:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-3 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-3:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-3 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-4:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-60%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-4:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-4 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-4:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-4 {
  display: block;
}
.s-type-1 #s-5:checked ~ .s-content {
  transform: translateX(-80%);
}
.s-type-1 #s-5:checked ~ .s-control .s-c-5 {
  background-color: #333;
}
.s-type-1 #s-5:checked ~ .s-nav .s-nav-5 {
  display: block;
}

.s-type-2 .s-content {
  animation: slider-animation 50s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.s-type-2 .s-content:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes slider-animation {
  0%,
    7% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  12.5%,
    19.5% {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
  25%,
    32% {
    transform: translateX(-40%);
  }
  37.5%,
    44.5% {
    transform: translateX(-60%);
  }
  50%,
    57% {
    transform: translateX(-80%);
  }
  62.5%,
    69.5% {
    transform: translateX(-60%);
  }
  75%,
    82% {
    transform: translateX(-40%);
  }
  87.5%,
    94.5% {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code but the arrows have disappeared. With the code of Mohit it works on my wordpress theme, I just have to resize my pictures. Thanks for your help !